# A line integral involving $\zeta(s)$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function

Let $x>1$ and $\zeta$ denote the Riemann zeta function. Is the equality

$$\int_{\sigma - i \infty}^{\sigma + i \infty} \frac{\zeta(s)x^{s}}{s(s+1)(s+2)\cdots (s+k)} \mathrm{d}s = 2\pi i$$ possible for any integer $k>1$ where $\sigma_{0}>1$ ?

Comment: The left-hand side is equal to $\frac{2\pi i}{k!} \sum_{n \leq x} (x - n)^k$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries, any proof or reference ?

Comment: Chapter 5 of Montgomery-Vaughan - the bit on Cesaro sums with $a_n = 1$ for all $n$, so that $\alpha(s) = \zeta(s)$.

Comment: @Peter Humphreys, thanks, just checked MV. But it seems your summand should rather be $(1-n/x)^k$...

Comment: Whoops, yep, that's correct